# Cannot create a zend framework project from the command line

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have done all the configurations required to run a zend framework project on the server,and its working fine.But when I try to create a new project from the command line,

**C:\wamp\www> zf create project myproject**

its not creating the project.Also its not giving any error.I have set the paths of php.exe and zf.bat.

**C:\wamp\www> zf show version** is also not doing anything.

There is not much information about this in the online documentation.

Comment: try zf.bat and see what it shows.

Comment: Enable the display of errors and the error reporting level to have all errors displayed: `ini_set('display_errors', '1'); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: I tried using zf.bat instead of zf but still nothing is hapenning.

Comment: It seems there was some problem in the zf.bat and zf.php files.I replaced them and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be something related to permission, depending on where the zf.bat is, I have experienced some issues when trying to call bat or similar files that are under certain C:/ folders. If that's not the problem, and you are not receiving any error messages in prompt when calling zf tool, check your Event Viewer, you can probably get more info about the error there.